# Login form for webapp refreshing endlessly on submit in IE 8, works fine in Firefox

Tags: java, internet-explorer, j-security-check

I have a simple username/password form that on submit does a `j_security_check` on an `LDAP` for user credentials.

Improper credentials behave as expected in both browsers, but when you give the form correct credentials and hit Submit, FF behaves as expected, but IE keeps refreshing a blank page endlessly.
I have no idea if this is a code or browser issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should install http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite on your browser to debug